# my reference photo has a weird rotation

Tags: coordinates

[image]

I am completely new to blender. I am following Blender Guru's instruction too create a 3d coffee mag. However, when I add a reference photo, it has been rotated automatically. I am pretty sure that I have never changed the coordinate. Why would this happen? What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome! You didn't add many details about how you added that image (did you use the addon "images as planes"?), or about your current "image object" like the current rotation, that you can view in the interface... if you mistakenly rotated it by accident, ALT-R performs a "clear rotation" command... try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably weren't in a front view when you imported your image, so select it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset its rotation. <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it, <kbd>G</kbd> to move it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly my mistake.